# Creating Dummy Variable for Two Events in Dataset and Restricting Regression by Time Period in Stata

Tags: linear-regression, stata

I am testing effect to two events in a dataset with a time dummy variable (post). For instance, my first event is in 1999 so I want to post-period after 1999 to 2003. Similarly, my second event is in 2010 so I want to set post period after 2010 to 2014. Accordingly, I want to set dummy variable (post) equals 1 for observations after post period and 0 for the pre periods.

One way I understand is to make a separate dataset for both the events and run. However, is there is anyway I could accomplish the same on this dataset ?

Additionally, if I want to run a liner regression is there is any command I could look into to restrict the regression for each event period ? So for first event run the regression until 2003 and for the second event until 2014

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you in advance

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str9 Ticker int Year str23 Industry double INBD float(ROA Size MTB LEV LOSS)
"TH:2S"    1995 "Industrials"             .36363636363636365           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    1996 "Industrials"              .2857142857142857           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    1997 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    1998 "Industrials"                           .375           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    1999 "Industrials"                           .625           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2000 "Industrials"             .26666666666666666           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2001 "Industrials"                           .375           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2002 "Industrials"             .21428571428571427           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2003 "Industrials"                            .25           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2004 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2005 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:2S"    2006 "Industrials"                              0   .05430601 13.347824         .  .4487669 0
"TH:2S"    2007 "Industrials"             .23076923076923078    .0748898 13.513892         .   .405519 0
"TH:2S"    2008 "Industrials"             .42857142857142855   .20173776 13.234512         .  .3000143 0
"TH:2S"    2009 "Industrials"                              0    .1005717  13.72495 1.1260449  .3933205 0
"TH:2S"    2010 "Industrials"              .2727272727272727   .06970939 13.839908 1.0841182 .43828955 0
"TH:2S"    2011 "Industrials"                             .4   .06131507 13.873565  .9524283  .4303303 0
"TH:2S"    2012 "Industrials"                              0   .04201316  14.04106  .9658951  .5001149 0
"TH:2S"    2013 "Industrials"                              0   .05576677 14.014296 1.0163808  .4338268 0
"TH:2S"    2014 "Industrials"                              0  .034753945 14.002456 1.6368295  .4192463 0
"TH:A"     1995 "Property & Construction" .45454545454545453           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     1996 "Property & Construction"                 .5           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     1997 "Property & Construction"                  0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     1998 "Property & Construction"                .25           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     1999 "Property & Construction" .13333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     2000 "Property & Construction"                 .4           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     2001 "Property & Construction"                 .5           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     2002 "Property & Construction"                 .6           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:A"     2003 "Property & Construction"  .3333333333333333  .025012556  14.53853         .  .6812668 0
"TH:A"     2004 "Property & Construction"                  0   .04457069 15.205904 1.6980723  .6221218 0
"TH:A"     2005 "Property & Construction"                  0 .0020386886 15.268938   2.07966  .6608869 0
"TH:A"     2006 "Property & Construction"  .3333333333333333  .001907199  15.27291  1.964063  .6603242 0
"TH:A"     2007 "Property & Construction"                  0 -.015466996  15.44163  1.918302  .7279775 1
"TH:A"     2008 "Property & Construction"                 .5  .005696189 15.559473  1.776193  .7537934 0
"TH:A"     2009 "Property & Construction" .46153846153846156   .09692752 15.491538  1.440211  .6395585 0
"TH:A"     2010 "Property & Construction" .42857142857142855   .07763009 15.522564 1.1848537  .5729401 0
"TH:A"     2011 "Property & Construction"                 .5  .013262192 15.561353 1.1070081 .57702786 0
"TH:A"     2012 "Property & Construction"                  0  .013741923 15.742103 1.2696354  .6365387 0
"TH:A"     2013 "Property & Construction"                  0 .0015351704  16.00987 1.7140155  .6814458 0
"TH:A"     2014 "Property & Construction"                  0 .0034536426  16.29612  1.858621  .7594991 0
"TH:AA"    1995 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333 -.006353655 16.525984  4.846756  .6370975 1
"TH:AA"    1996 "Industrials"                              0   -.0462963 16.797165  5.059855  .7687468 1
"TH:AA"    1997 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333     -.17009 17.534548  2.606452  .8492652 1
"TH:AA"    1998 "Industrials"              .4166666666666667   .11416897  17.54763  .7374102  .6734178 0
"TH:AA"    1999 "Industrials"                            .25  -.11794188 17.270618  2.397937  .8667688 1
"TH:AA"    2000 "Industrials"              .5384615384615384  .019639796  17.28194  1.632345  .8497713 0
"TH:AA"    2001 "Industrials"              .2222222222222222  .006626872 17.217733  1.587646  .8325074 0
"TH:AA"    2002 "Industrials"             .35714285714285715   .04131401  17.18029 1.2312752  .7847582 0
"TH:AA"    2003 "Industrials"                           .375   .05050331 17.203983 2.1328473  .7387649 0
"TH:AA"    2004 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333   .05501763 17.133413  1.411802  .6652893 0
"TH:AA"    2005 "Industrials"                              0  .064267844 17.207062 1.1283801  .5871332 0
"TH:AA"    2006 "Industrials"                             .2  .065511316 17.220182  1.377417  .5249598 0
"TH:AA"    2007 "Industrials"              .4444444444444444  .015064287 17.167637 1.3882604  .4864591 0
"TH:AA"    2008 "Industrials"                            .25           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AA"    2009 "Industrials"              .4444444444444444           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AA"    2010 "Industrials"              .3333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AA"    2011 "Industrials"             .14285714285714285           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AA"    2012 "Industrials"                              0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AA"    2013 "Industrials"                              0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AA"    2014 "Industrials"                              0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   1995 "Services"                .23076923076923078           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   1996 "Services"                              .375           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   1997 "Services"                 .3333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   1998 "Services"                                 0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   1999 "Services"                                 0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2000 "Services"                 .4666666666666667           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2001 "Services"                                 0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2002 "Services"                              .375           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2003 "Services"                                 0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2004 "Services"                                .2           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2005 "Services"                                .5           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2006 "Services"                                 0           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2007 "Services"                              .375           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2008 "Services"                .36363636363636365           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:AAV"   2009 "Services"                 .3333333333333333  -.08246704 14.541677         .  3.183686 1
"TH:AAV"   2010 "Services"                                 0     .413217 15.397943         .  1.514293 0
"TH:AAV"   2011 "Services"                                 0   .53301877 15.147836         . 1.1440629 0
"TH:AAV"   2012 "Services"                 .3333333333333333     .473854 17.312746  .8970968 .20764913 0
"TH:AAV"   2013 "Services"                 .3333333333333333  .023205843 17.620733  .6654471  .4063622 0
"TH:AAV"   2014 "Services"                 .3333333333333333  .003700512  17.71752  .7719533  .4542441 0
"TH:ABICO" 1995 "Agro & Food Industry"    .36363636363636365           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:ABICO" 1996 "Agro & Food Industry"     .3333333333333333           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:ABICO" 1997 "Agro & Food Industry"                   .25           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:ABICO" 1998 "Agro & Food Industry"     .4444444444444444           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:ABICO" 1999 "Agro & Food Industry"    .23076923076923078           .         .         .         . 0
"TH:ABICO" 2000 "Agro & Food Industry"     .3333333333333333   -.4316369 14.122723         . 2.2422733 1
"TH:ABICO" 2001 "Agro & Food Industry"     .2727272727272727    .2456064  14.19583         . 1.2081953 0
"TH:ABICO" 2002 "Agro & Food Industry"    .36363636363636365  -.13187617 14.014474         . 1.4432036 1
"TH:ABICO" 2003 "Agro & Food Industry"                     0  -.20122433  13.85465         . 1.7235887 1
"TH:ABICO" 2004 "Agro & Food Industry"                    .5  -1.2570164  13.76754         .  3.056561 1
"TH:ABICO" 2005 "Agro & Food Industry"                    .2   2.2142339 13.705672         .   .929168 0
"TH:ABICO" 2006 "Agro & Food Industry"     .3333333333333333   .04549691 13.680099         .  .9444808 0
"TH:ABICO" 2007 "Agro & Food Industry"    .45454545454545453   .14073876 13.111873         . 1.5902317 0
"TH:ABICO" 2008 "Agro & Food Industry"                     0  -.07876977  12.94573         . 1.7910005 1
"TH:ABICO" 2009 "Agro & Food Industry"     .3333333333333333   .11251536  13.14271         . 1.2879436 0
"TH:ABICO" 2010 "Agro & Food Industry"                     0   .05981953 13.178632         . 1.1793016 0
"TH:ABICO" 2011 "Agro & Food Industry"                     0    .1542739 13.224712         .  .9512552 0
"TH:ABICO" 2012 "Agro & Food Industry"                    .3   .22630814  13.71115         .  .5845832 0
"TH:ABICO" 2013 "Agro & Food Industry"                    .3    .1281038 13.741155         . .54510576 0
"TH:ABICO" 2014 "Agro & Food Industry"                    .3   .10894921 13.825327         .  .4710184 0
end
format %ty Year
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* Indicator variable for pre/post
gen post = .
replace post = 0 if inrange(Year,1999,2003)
replace post = 1 if inrange(Year,2010,2014)

* Separate regressions for each event period
regress y x1 x2 if post == 0
regress y x1 x2 if post == 1
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But when I use this it actually assigns 0 for post period of my first event (1999-2003) and 1 to the post period of my second event (2010-2014).

But my ambition was to assign the value 0 for pre period once for the first event from (1995-1998) and 1 for the post period for the second event (1999-2003).

Subsequently, I want to assign the value 0 for pre period for the second event from (2004-2010) and the value 1 for the post period from (2011-2014). 

Thank you once again for your help

Comment: Which variable defines the "first" and "second" events?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and  my apologies for the super late reply. Taking from your question I believe I would need to make a separate dataset for the first and second event then create the dummy variables, as I did not set any variables that would define the first and second event